# JPA Hibernate Change Fetch type from Lazy To Eager for multiple child entities based on condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, jparepository

Parent Entity

- Product

  ```
  public class ProductEntity extends BaseEntity {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "product_uuid", nullable = false)
   private String uuid;

   @Column(name = "sku", nullable = true)
   private Long sku;

   @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
   private String name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<ProductInfoEntity> infos;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private Set<ProductTaxEntity> taxes;
  }
  ```

Child Entity

- Info
- Tax

Only few cases child entities required to fetch eagerly. Is there any way to change child entity fetch type from lazy to eager in either of the framework **JPARepository/ CriteriaQuery/SQL**

Tried almost every solution on stack overflow but every-time code will hit many queries to retrieve child entities

Comment: You'll have to explain what you are seeing multiple queries for exactly. As this is a OneToMany from Product->Child, you should only see 1 query to bring in the many children in that relationship. If you are reading in many products and so seeing N queries when iterating over the results and fetching their children, you'll want to read http://briaguy.blogspot.com/2017/05/jpa-fetch-behavior-eclipselink-and.html which has a good discussion on various options on what is called batch fetching in eclipseLink, or use fetching in the query by specifying fetch joins or a load graph

Answer (score 0):

It's called N+1 problem in hibernate, You can solve it by using below methodologies...

```
-> By using JOIN FETCH
-> By using @EntityGraph and Projection
```

Because JOIN FETCH will make always single query for multiple tables using join internally.